# Bad Questions: Close votes v. Down votes

Tags: discussion, downvotes, bad-questions

To anyone coming to this question after its closure, downvoting notifications are status declined [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c)

### The Problem

UserX asks a really terrible question. As it should be, it is rapidly closed and in the process accumulates a few downvotes. After reading the close reason, UserX thinks, "Oh, I wrote this up in a very unclear way, and I can fix this question so it makes sense now." So, they fix the question and now their question goes to the reopen queue (I think). Because it's a good question, it is reopened. Everything is great and the system worked!

But wait! The question the UserX asked still has a score of -4 from people who downvoted for the same reason the question was closed, and UserX will in all likelihood never get their answer, or get the downvotes reversed.

In this situation, the downvoters were right to downvote at the time because the question was unclear. So were the close voters. And once the question was fixed those who voted to reopen were also right. UserX was right to fix the question instead of asking it again. But the downvoters have no idea that UserX has now written a great question, so they won't go back to reverse the downvotes.

### The Solution<sup>1</sup>

<strike>I think that it is not necessary to flag/close vote a question to then also downvote it for the same reason you flagged/close voted it. Flags should be for problem questions, downvotes should be for questions that are not useful.</strike>

I think that we would like to keep users like UserX who learns from their mistake and tries to help improve bad content. But I think that if UserX was a new user they would probably be scared away from Stack Overflow because downvotes are (in my opinion) taken as rude and scare people away rather than just having their question closed.

Part of that is because if a question is closed, there is easy access for information on how to fix it in the close vote reason. If your question is downvoted, it's very hard to get back above 0 from -2 or less especially without guidance from the downvoters (although I don't think downvoters should be obligated to give guidance). I think that we should encourage users to flag/close vote OR downvote instead of doing both to maintain a slightly better community.

This is not actually a good solution.

<sub>1: Not actually a solution, just an idea for what might be a possible solution. If you have a better idea please add it as an answer. I tagged this as discussion because I don't have the answer and would like to start a discussion about a possible solution.</sub>

Comment: "Problem questions" also generally fall into the category of "not useful" questions. What you observe is of course true. You only get one chance to ask a good question. If you blow it, your odds of getting a good answer aren't nearly as good the second time. Think of it as an incentive to work hard enough to get it right the first time.

Comment: @CodyGray But shouldn't new users get a chance to learn from their mistakes? The route shouldn't be "the only way to get a good answer is to deleted my question with downvotes and ask again"

Comment: In my experience, when a user is capable of asking a good, well thought-out question, they will typically do so the first time around. If they're not able to articulate their problem showing proper research and effort put forth the first time, they're usually not able to do it the second time either. New users that make such honest mistakes are rare. The ones that do have issues usually have minor issues that don't lead to massive downvoting. That all said, this is purely anecdotal from my own experience.

Comment: `The route shouldn't be "the only way to get a good answer is to deleted my question with downvotes and ask again"` Maybe it shouldn't - but the downsides of your solution, as it stands, really outweigh the benefits. There *is* an element of "you need to get it right the first time" in the big city that is Stack Overflow - it can be an unforgiving place sometimes. There may not be a technological solution to that. (These, days it can be hard to get it right even to a seasoned professional who is just new to Stack Overflow and its myriad rules and regulations - but that's a different issue.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 I agree. I tried to say in the question that you should take my solution with a grain of salt, I don't really have a solution. If I did this would be a feature request.

Comment: `If I did this would be a feature request.` OK - but take note that it will likely be treated as one (i.e. folks who disagree may downvote it, in true Meta spirit, even though there's nothing wrong with it quality-wise.)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Should I remove the solution section?

Comment: It would seem incomplete without it. I'd leave it. [Everyone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=145) has downvoted suggestions around here.

Comment: It is theoretically possible, been a long time since I've seen that work.  With today's massive question volume you get only one chance to make a good first impression.  Users are smart enough to figure this out by themselves, no help required, they just delete the bad question and repost a better one.

Comment: From my experience, if you respond fast enough and edit the question and/or clarify things in the comments, some close-votes and downvotes will be reverted. I'm usually leaving the question open in one tab to see if the OP edited their question. But I don't care about questions I downvoted hours ago, and notification will not help - Let someone else upvote/reopen. That's the OP's fault for asking bad question and delay their improvement response

Answer (score 3):

As a new user I think that a few downvotes don't get in the way of trying to ask a good question. My reputation went down from 10 to 2 after trying to ask a regex question which should probably have been saved as a draft. Since the idea of the post was clear, I posted it. When I returned one of three downvoters said "you have three problems now". The downvotes were significant but the comment was useless. I edited the post and some downvotes were reversed. If downvoters are notified of changes/additions to posts they are involved in, I think they should be prepared to reverse their downvote.